# One Way Cryptographic

Tags: cryptography, blockchain

Assume you can use a strong one-way cryptographic hash function that takes a string of variable length as an input, producing a fixed length output that is unique for each input string. It is computationally infeasible to reverse this process.

If you use a document as the input of the hashing function, what can you do with the output hash? This question has more than one answer.

What is the correct choices 
**a**: Compare whether you have the same document as someone else without comparing the documents themselves
**b**: Send the hash to another party for them to decrypt the hash to retrieve the document
**c**: Create a table where anyone who has the hash can find the document
**d**: Compress the document content so it can be extracted later

Comment: This looks like a homework dump. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: What is the exact definition of "computationally infeasible"?

Comment: It was a test that I have passed but I ddint know what was the correct answers If it is possible plz tell me the correct answers

Comment: @FabianPijcke Generally that the sun will go die before the computation completes.

Comment: Yes, but is it by current technological means or taking into account future hardware performances?

Comment: Because as the output is of fixed length, I guess we can imagine that in short term, it will be possible to "crack" it, be it by storing every hash because we will have space enough to do so, or by reversing by any other means ...

Comment: @FabianPijcke Typically a result is desired within a human lifetime.

Comment: @FabianPijcke Store 2^256 hashes along with the data which may also be large. Still there is the issue that there exist several different inputs that result in the same hash.

Comment: "output that is unique for each input string"? Unique? Really unique? Well, then a and c are valid. It also means that the fixed length output must be longer than any valid input. Sounds like a stupid hash function.

Comment: I agree with Art, I think that there is no correct answer for such a function does not actually exist :D

Comment: Consider Git and the fact that hashes are used to identify files. Consider current usage. Consider that an answer in the range a-d is required.

Comment: Yes but it only assumes that collisions are rare enough to use the hash as a check. There is still a chance that the file is corrupted, which is why md5 should not be used anymore : Someone can corrupt a file slightly by adding a block of comments that will "restore" the initial hash.

Comment: "Someone can corrupt a file slightly by adding a block of comments that will "restore" the initial hash." Try it. While MD5 should not in general be used does not mean that there are no use cases where it is acceptable.

Comment: I never said it was easy, but papers give the technique for a particular case, so md5 should not be used anymore because it is probably possible to do it for any language. Besides I'm no cryptography researcher ^^

Comment: See the accepted answer here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138363/why-is-md5-considered-a-vulnerable-algorithm

Comment: The  security.stackexchange question is about passwords, a very different use case. This question is about documents, not passwords. This question does not mention MD5.

Comment: Well ... I was just answering your "try it." question, with a reference stating explicitly "There are techniques to find a plaintext that produces a desired MD5." ...

Comment: What is the problem or question? Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question."*

Answer (score 2):

Since this is not an answer for a curent question:

a: is a correct answer. *"Compare whether you have the same document as someone else without comparing the documents themselves."*

This is a common use of cryptographicly secure hashes, Git is one use case.

c. Is a potential answer as a hash can be used in this manner. *"Create a table where anyone who has the hash can find the document."*

The other answers are all incorrect because the original can not be recovered from the hash.